# i am having trouble finding a way to host my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

Back in December i started writing my very first Rails app. It's a non profit app for managing sports clubs. Now, after two months of struggle, version 0.5 is ready for deployment, there is still a lot of room for improvements and enhancements, but it has reached a level where input from peer review and user testing is required. I am very impressed as to how far i have come in such short time. (I'm a seasoned developer, but i am new to everything in the rails universe). To facilitate the review and test i wanted to "publish" it, only to discover that this is not very easy. I have been unable to find any hosting for my app that is not very costly (compared to PHP or, to an extent, .NET). I Fund one provider, but after finally getting in touch with them they told me that they could do it "in theory", but their ruby version was probably "way too old". I'm located in Denmark, so hosting in the US is not an option (the app will have member info and i have been led to believe that hosting personal info outside the scope of European GDPR is illegal. This might and might not be true, but i won't go there). PHP hosting in Denmark (shared) costs around 4 euros a month, but the only thing i have been able to find for Rails is VPS at around 27 euros a month. I need some suggestions around ways to host my app without paying a fortune.

p.s. I have found several questions like this, but all of them are very old (5+ years).

Comment: This is not a bad question but is not an on-topic subject for Stackoverflow as we don't do software or service recommendations as they attract spam and are mostly just opinion based ("I tried X and it worked for me!"). You might want to try the chat or something like https://www.reddit.com/r/rubyonrails/ which are open to discussions - remember that this is a Q&A site. Not a discussion forum. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I'm sorry, i was not aware of this. I just had no idea where else to go, the community has been very helpful so far.

Comment: Heroku and many other cloud hosting providers offer a free hobby tier which is usually perfectly adequate for small apps. Once you have outgrown that hopefully you have a way to finance more dynos/resources such as donations or a grant. Deploying Rails on public hosting has never really been a viable option - hell deploying else then wordpress is usually a nightmare since they use really old versions of PHP with crappy builds and no shell access. Its a dead concept for anything beyond brocureware.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Depending on your app, it might be free. Might not be. I've used it to host my hobby-projects.

Another option is to get a generic linux machine and install ruby and everything else you need yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will seek info elsewhere.